# How to create a translucent overlay using JavaScript in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

In ReactJS project, I have an API request and once I make it, I would like to render a translucent overlay on the current webpage with Material UI's progress indicator ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/circular-progress )on top of the translucent overlay, and after I get a response back, would like for the translucent overlay with the progress indicator to go away.

How can I go about doing so? Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service but we're happy to help debug if you run into problems

Answer (score 0):

In React, you can use the `backgroundColor` and `RGBA` css, so for example

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}}> ... </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand but how can I get it to to cover the whole page temporarily?

Comment: Just like you would normally do with css